# CKEditor Creating an editor after closing the first one doesn't load

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, editor

I have an click-to-edit editor that uses the CKeditor. When you click on an editable section a CKeditor replaces the text and you can edit it. The problem is after you click "cancel" or "save" and then try to edit again the editor doesn't load. I've tried a lot of solutions on here (destroy(true) before recreating the editor for example) but nothing works. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here is my code:

```
$(".editable").click(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var target = $this;
            var thisText = $this.html();

            $("<textarea />").addClass("currentField").attr("ID","currentFieldID")
                .val(thisText)
                .appendTo(target);

            var allInstances=CKEDITOR.instances;
            for ( var i in allInstances ){
                allInstances[i].destroy(true);
            }
            CKEDITOR.replace("currentFieldID");

            $("<input type='button' value='Save' /> ").click(function(event) {
                    var newText=$('.currentField').val();

                    CKEDITOR.instances['currentFieldID'].destroy(true);

                    //Save

                    event.stopPropagation();
                }).addClass("saveBtn").button().appendTo(target);

            $("<input type='button' value='Cancel' />").click(function(event) {
                    var newText=$('.currentField').val();

                    CKEDITOR.instances['currentFieldID'].destroy(true);


                    //cancel

                    event.stopPropagation();
                }).addClass("cancelBtn").button().appendTo(target);
});
```

Here are some photos to show the problem:

The first time looks like this:

[image: What it looks like the fist time I load the ckeditor:]

The second time looks like this:

[image: What it looks like the second time I load the ckeditor]

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was with a plugin I was using. I removed the plugin and it started working.